# UIAlertView dismissal in utility class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

In my application i want alertview in many views.So what i did is just wrote a single alertview in a utility class and use it everywhere.This is working fine.

I even tried by setting `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` but in vain.

Utility Class

```
    @interface SSUtility: NSObject<UIAlertViewDelegate> {

    }

    +(void)showAllert;
    @end


    @implementation SSUtility    
         +(void)showAllert{
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"gotoappAppstore",@"") message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [alert show];
          [alert release];
        }
        @end

Now from my view

 -(void)pressButton{
[SSutility showAllert]

}
```

Now i want to give a button action for alert view click and call a method on that button action.

So im stuck with,in which class i want to implement this method.I tried it in utility class and viewc controller but the method is not getting triggered when "ok" button is pressed.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share all relevant code for setting your `UIAlertView` up. So basically include your utility class and then the both that you call this from other classes.

Comment: Did you set `alertView.delegate = self;` (or another object instead of self)?

Comment: @Popeye,@pNre please check my code.

Answer (score 1):

You wire the alert view button response method by setting your alert view object delegate usually to the owner object and implementing the – alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method.

You need 4 parts in your code:

1. instantiate your UIAlertView object
2. send show message to your UIAlertView object
3. set delegate
4. implement the delegate method

Example:

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myTitle" message:@"myMessage" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitle:@"Another button"];
[myAlertView setDelegate:self];
[myAlertView show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
    {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) //index 0 is cancel, I believe
        {
        // code for handling cancel tap in your alert view
        }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
        // code for handling button with index 1
        }
    }
```

I would recommend you get more familiar with how delegates work.  This'll come back again a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You set `delegate:nil` in your `UIAlertView`'s init.

You should set to `delegate:self`, like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"gotoappAppstore",@"") message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

in order to use the delegate in the same class (a.k.a. `self`).

As a sidenote, if you use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you do not need `[alert release]` (your Xcode compiler should warn you about this)

Comment: even after setting the delegate as self,result is same.not working :(

Comment: Have you set `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` like `@interface SSUtility: NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>`???

Comment: @Raptor I agree but in the code he has shared it isn't there and the only thing I can think of that is stopping this from working is the fact that it is missing.